Getting Exception trying to use Methods in Referenced DLL, C# (Visual Studio)
I am currently working on a project where i have to reference a DLL file, Which i have, but i keep getting this error when i try to access methods in the DLL. It fails on the first line, saying "Load Library Failed".

Here is the code
try
{
    var devices = DeviceManager.GetAvailableDevices();
    var attachedDevices = DeviceManager.GetAttachedDevices(DeviceIdentity.FG_ZF1);
    if (attachedDevices.Length > 0)
    {
        _capDevice = DeviceManager.GetDevice(DeviceIdentity.FG_ZF1, attachedDevices[0].index);
        _capDevice.CaptureMode = CaptureMode.PREVIEW_IMAGE_AUTO_DETECT;
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}


Please include the complete exception in your question. (You shouldn't need to show the text visualizer - just copy/paste the complete exception including full message, stack trace, and any inner exceptions). A [mcve] would make this easier to understand as well, particularly if this is an open source library so we can reproduce it.

Can you make sure that the platform(x86 or x64) of your project is the same as the DLL file? In addition, it is recommended to share contents of your DLL file.
